# re-using a component with nested states in multiple parents angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a component called person. Within the person component I have a series of tabs - the content for each is rendered in a ui-view via a state linked to a component. One of these tabs contains notes. I have created a notes component which has a ui-view for child states for the standard master-detail components (list, add, view, edit). I also have another component called Project. Within the project component, I also need notes, so would like to be able to reuse the same notes component. How can I dynamically set the parent on the notes state so that I can render it in the tab on the relevant component(person or project). I did get it to dynamically set the parent on the notes top level state by using $stateParams in a function to set the parent (and this displays), but the child states of the note state do not display, so I need to know how to propagate that down. I'm sure it is simple, but I have tried a million combinations and can't get it right. Please see below the template for the nacNote component - the List link doesn't do anything. As well as the state configs for the two states.

```
var noteTemplate = `
    <h3>
        Notes
        <nac-link-button text="" glyph="circle-plus" on-click="$ctrl.add();"></nac-link-button>
    </h3>
    <a ui-sref="note_list">List</a> //link doesn't work
    <ui-view></ui-view>
`;
var stateNote = {
  name: 'note_admin',
  url: '/note',
  parent: function ($stateParams) { return $stateParams.parent;},
  component: 'nacNote'
};
var stateNoteList = {
  name: 'note_list',
  parent: 'note_admin',
  component: 'nacNoteList',    
};
angular
  .module('nacNote', ['nacForm'])
  .service('nacNoteService', NoteService)
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state(stateNote)
        .state(stateNoteList)
    ;

  })
  .component('nacNote', note)
  .component('nacNoteList', noteList)
```

;

the relevant person template and state config - this works

```
var personNoteTemplate = `
    <div>Person Note</div>
    <nac-note parent="person_note"></nac-note>
`;

 .state('person_note', {
            parent: 'person_view',
            url: '/note',
            component: 'nacPersonNote'
        })
```